# invalid_grant error with docusign nodejs client

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I use docusign nodejs client to get the JWT User Token and it worked perfectly until suddenly got the "invalid_grant" error from docusign yesterday. I didn't make any code change so didn't know how to fix it. Is there any one got the same error ? Below are some error info:

```
        status: 400,
        text: '{"error":"invalid_grant"}',
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/oauth/token'
```

Comment: status: 400 refers to "The server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, size too large, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)" can you share your code?

Comment: The "invalid_grant" error is very specific for docusign logic, so I think it is more relating to their api logic. I follow the code in this repository https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-node-jwt/issues/1 , my implementation has too many company logic so I can't share now.  Thanks

Comment: you didn't change your code, but maybe you made configuration changes?

Comment: can you check on your IK in the admin console? check your RSA key and ensure it's still valid? and is not being stored incorrectly?

Comment: Thank @InbarGazit, you are right that the RSA key was deleted by someone in my team. I created a new one and my function works again.

Comment: thanks, I'll add an answer to that effect, please mark this as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a valid RSA key that matches the key you got in the DocuSign Admin. The key might be the issue in this case.